# Should I install drivers on a Dell Inspiron 5559?

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron

I just installed a fresh-from-Microsoft Windows 10 on a Dell Inspiron 5559. Dell offers around 20 files to download and install for drivers and other things. At least one of those won't run due to Microsoft not recognizing the vendor. Some look like really outdated installers at least. Should I install them?

It looks like Windows by itself is installing most of the drivers. Most of the computer seems to be working fine. What's the best path here to have something clean and nice, like a Windows Signature Edition computer?

Comment: Just install the drivers required for the devices to work, any driver not specifically labeled for Windows, shouldn't be installed

Answer (score 1):

More often than not, Microsoft has drivers for your hardware.  But also more often than not, the manufacturer has 'special features' or other things that only come with their drivers.

If it were my machine, I would install *all* the manufacturer's drivers, since they are *explicitly designed* to work with your *exact* hardware.

In other words, you don't need them, but it can't hurt to install them if they're good (which Dell is a noteworthy company, so they are reputable).

Comment: in Win10 the drivers from WU include all features. I saw that the AMD driver also includes the CCC.

Comment: Is that a 100% always includes all features?

Comment: I got the full drivers with all features.

Comment: Maybe you did, but not necessarily everyone will.  It can't hurt to install the manufacturer's drivers.

Comment: You can install mfg drivers but windows update will install the latest versions automatically. No way to stop this either.

Comment: Moab is correct, that's why the WU drivers are the full complete drivers.

Comment: OK.  I'm not that familiar with Win10's driver updater.  I'm used to Windows XP's complete lack of usefulness.