# How do I switch between graphic cards in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 5559 that comes with two graphic cards, an onboard Intel one and a Radeon:

[image]

How do I switch to using the Radeon card instead of the Intel one?

I have installed a fresh Windows 10 Pro from Microsoft. [I haven't installed the drivers form Dell yet because I'm not sure they are required](https://superuser.com/questions/1003422/should-i-install-drivers-on-a-dell-inspiron-5559) and my experience when I tried installing them was not very good.

Comment: Just install the current AMD and Intel display drivers from their respective websites.

Comment: Don't they run together anyway because one is an integrated graphics card? I have an AMD APU and a graphics card and they run together.

Answer (score 1):

Like @ramhound said, install the [AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) and [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/) drivers. You should be able to find more information in the AMD Catalyst Control Center after you install the driver.

You may also want to check out [How to install AMD driver for ATI Dynamic Switchable Graphics in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/728953/how-to-install-amd-driver-for-ati-dynamic-switchable-graphics-in-windows-7)

You should also be able to disable the integrated graphics in the BIOS, if that's what you really want. Keep in mind this will negatively affect battery life and heat.

Comment: Should I install the drivers from Intel and AMD or from Dell? Dell, in the list of drivers and software to install, mentions many that should be installed before the video ones. Would this be an issue: http://www.dell.com/support/home/UK/en/rc1050266/product-support/servicetag/8CD9662/drivers ?

Comment: You can't go wrong installing the driver from Dell, but you may benefit from getting a (possibly) newer one from AMD and Intel.